# Unable to uninstall dropbox in a roaming profile or to delete data from an existing dropbox

Tags: windows, sync, dropbox, user-profiles, roaming-profiles

For several years i had a running dropbox installation pointing to a home directory on a network drive associated with my roaming profile in a windows 2012 environment.
Some days ago, i realized that previously deleted files are constantly uploaded again to my dropbox. Ive found out that these old files are coming from the roaming profile folder. This seems to be related to the recently showing up startup message that my profile is uncompletely synced.

I tried to deinstall dropbox locally and delete manually all instances in appdata/roaming and the registry from the local profile, but in the end, this is always reversed.
The dropbox installation status is restored from the roaming profile upon startup of the local machine.

To solve this, what needs my network administrator to do?

edit:
according to [this link](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/288859-how-do-you-install-dropbox-if-you-use-roaming-profiles) Dropbox shouldnt be used in roaming profiles. I was unaware of that, and i wonder how it run smoothly for years. A solution to my current problem is still very much welcome.